# Problem using Firefox ESR 45.4.0 and Vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, firefox, vuejs2

I am trying to deploy a vue application. I have to use Firefox ESR as browser (45.4.0) but I get the following error: `TypeError: Object.values is not a function`. If I use a different browser it works fine.
Could anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: please show us the code

Comment: It is a big application... it is impossible to show it here...I think  it is a compatibility problem...is there anyway of compile vue.js for this browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) was introduced in Firefox 47.

Your browser is from 2015. That is **hideously ancient** in Internet terms. Upgrade it.

(If you really want to to get the Vue application to work, you'll need to set up a Polyfill for `Object.values`. There is one linked from the MDN page I linked to above. It should also be available in [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) which can be used with Babel in the transpiling step of your build process.)

Comment: And how could I do that? I know nothing about polyfill...and I am in a rush with this...could you help me please?

Comment: I suggested two you could use in the answer!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the links. Thank you very much! Now it works perfectly